# undefined variable on view

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to be able to access this variable on controller that i had make before

this is my code in my view

```
 <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($data->result() as $row):?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row->nama; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->password; ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/edit/'.$row->username); ?>">Edit</a> | 
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/delete/'.$row->username); ?>" onCLick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')">DELETE</a> | 
          </td>  
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
```

i put some method that contain that variable on controller name Login, but i set my default controller as News. And i want to access that variable from Login Controller.

and this is my Login Controller

```
public function index()
{

    $this->$data['login'] = $this->Login_Model->get_news();
    $this->$data['title']= 'Data Pendaftaran';

    // konfigurasi pagination//
    $config['base_url']     = site_url('Login/index');
    $config['total_rows']   = $this->db->count_all('anggota');
    $config['per_page']     =4;
    $config["uri_segment"]  =3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"]/ $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"]    =floor($choice);

    // style pagination untuk bootstrap v4//
    $config['first_link']       = 'First';
    $config['last_link']        = 'Last';
    $config['next_link']        = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link']        = 'Prev';
    $config['full_tag_open']    = '<div class="pagging text-center"><nav><ul class = "pagination justify-content-center">';
    $config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul></nav></div>';
    $config['num_tag_open']     ='<li class="page-item"><span class ="page-link">';
    $config['num_tag_close']    ='</span></li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open']     ='<li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['cur_tag_close']    ='<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>';
    $config['next_tag_open']    ='<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['next_tagl_close']  ='<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></span></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open']    ='<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['prev_tagl_close']  ='</span>Next</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open']   ='<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</span></li>';
    $config['last_tag_open']    ='<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['last_tagl_close']  ='</span></li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['page']=($this->uri->segment(3))? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['data'] = $this->Login_Model->get_data_list($config["per_page"],$data['page']);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('anggotapendaftaran',$data);
}
```

im sorry for my bad language

Comment: Is it CodeIgniter?

Comment: So, you want pass parameter from Controller to View?

Comment: yeah its codeigniter, and i want to pass the variable from Controller to view

Comment: please be specific, where is "news"? how is this related to the above code? what variable are you trying to access in the view (where is it defined)? what is your current approach?

Comment: What variable is undefined in your view?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

On Controller, after you all code where you load view:

```
$data = array();
$data['title'] = 'Data Pendaftaran';
$this->load->view("yourviewname_view", $data);
```

on View, when you want to get title, you can get it like $data
example:

```
echo $data; //will give you "Data Pendaftaran"
```

If it's array, you can access it like:

```
echo $data['arrayKey'];
```

or

```
echo $data['pagination'];
```

I hope this will help